# Fullcalendar not rendering events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have this code that creates an array of event objects, which is then passed into the calendar, but for some reason the calendar does not render the events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,   
        events: function(start, end,  timezone, callback) {
                            $.ajax({
                success: function(doc) {
                    var events = [];
                    $.getJSON('../php/logg.php', function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(key, val){
                        var temp = moment($(this).attr('dato'))
                        if(temp.isBefore(start)){ return true; }
                        else if(temp.isAfter(end)){ return true; }
                        else{x
                            events.push({
                                id: $(this).attr('id'),
                                title: $(this).attr('artist'),
                                start: $(this).attr('dato'),
                                allDay: false
                                });
                            }
                        }
                       );
                    });
                    var ektearray = $.makeArray(events);    
                    callback(events);
                }   
        });
    }
});
});
```

When I output events to the console I get an array of objects, which seem to be working as expected. The objects are in the form:

```
allDay:false
id:"66"
start:"2016-11-04"
title:"Galantis"
__proto__:Object
```

It seems like I am either messing up the callback, or that my events are missing something, but I can't seem to figure out what

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to execute the `function(doc)` upon success of the `ajax` call. If so, your syntax seems no to be properly written.

```
    $.ajax({
             method: "POST",
             url: "some.php",
             data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
          })
      .success(function() {
        alert( "success" );
      });
```